# Silverlight data refresh loop

Tags: silverlight, ria

I am sure that with as many dashboard apps out there, people have come across this issue.  I have a SL app that needs to loop continuously, calling a RIA service to pull in data updates, with some minimal timer delay (e.g. 3 sec).  It is an MVVM solution, and the data being refreshed on the client will likely be wrapped in a PagedCollectionView.

Are there any common (tr: tried and tested) approaches to fetching the data the first time and updating/appending new data in this fashion?  It is purely read-only data, there is no editing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a timer (that is not set to recur) to pull the data. When the data comes back, restart the timer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  This is the approach I first came to, but thought there might be something a little more elegant.

Comment: There are several approaches. Some may use less lines of code but I doubt I'd consider them more "elegant" as situations like this are what the timer is for.